# Symfony impersonate a User and multiple firewall

Tags: php, symfony, impersonation

I have a problem with a feature of symfony. When I impersonate a User and I make a call to my API the user is not the impersonate.

Here is my security config:

```
api:
    pattern:   ^/api/.*
    provider: fos_userbundle
    guard:
        authenticators:
            - app.wsse_authenticator
            - app.form_login_authenticator
        entry_point: app.wsse_authenticator
    logout:       true
    stateless: true
    anonymous:    true
    switch_user: true
    context: my_context
main:
    pattern:   ^/.*
    provider: fos_userbundle
    guard:
        authenticators:
            - app.form_login_authenticator
    switch_user: true
    logout:       true
    anonymous:    true
    remember_me:
        secret:      "%secret%"
        lifetime: 7200 # in seconds (=12h)
        always_remember_me: true
    context: my_context
```

I tried to use the same context to share the impersonate user between both firewall but it's not working.

When a make a request on `/test` the impersonate user is used but when I make a request on `/api/test` the user is me and not the impersonate.

Someone could help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that what you're trying to do would not work the way you'd want it.

The `API` firewall is `stateless`, which means that there is no `session` involved in the authentication. Usually with a `REST API` you send a `TOKEN` with your request via setting a `header` or as part of the request - `http://localhost/api/users?apiKey=my_key_goes_here` which is how you authenticate.

On the other hand in the `main` firewall the authentication is done via a session. The authentication credentials (i.e. `UserToken`) are stored in the a `session` and then they are used each time the user makes a request to a url of your site.

Having a `context` would have worked if both `firewalls` were `session` based. In this particular case the authentication methods are simply incompatible which is why you can't simply click on the `Symfony development tool bar` and `impersonate` another user.

Doing a simple search in [packagist](https://packagist.org) I found [SwitchUserStatelessBundle](https://github.com/lafourchette/SwitchUserStatelessBundle) which might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Hello have you tried using this package, I tried integrating it but was unable to use it. Wondering what api call should be made to get the token of the switched user?

Comment: I haven't used the package and it's now 4 years old so it might not be working anymore with Symfony 4.3+/5.1+. As for the endpoint - you can implement a custom endpoint to specifically generate such tokens to allow user impersonation. You will need to be EXTREMELY careful with the implementation and avoid security breaches.